# Identify type in a generic portable way in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, c++11

Is there any way to identify a type in a generic and portable way for serialization? I know `std::type_index` and `std::type_info` are platform dependent and can't be used for serialization.

One way would be to make a map between `std::type_index` and one "type information" and to serialize the "type information", but this will slow down the serialization.

Is there any standard way of doing this?

PS: I want to learn how to do efficient serialization, I don't want to use a library.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you're not going to use a library, then you'll find yourself writing one. C++ makes it hard with no reflection.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use a library, you could start by looking at how one is written, e.g. at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "portable". If you're going to read the data with the same binary that wrote it, you can get away with using the `type_index` directly. If performance is *that* critical, you can always do that and use a separate function (perhaps running in a separate process) to collect the raw data and serialize it in a saner way.

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to use same library, but on different platforms. I want to write the files on PC and read them on different mobile platforms. I think type traits is the best solutions for this - to get "serializable type" from the real type and to get the real type from the "serializable type"

Comment: non-trivial types have to support serialization anyway. so, just register a unique id, such as an UUID, for each such type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm thinking of using a Serialize(...) function for non-trivial types. The type should know how to serialize itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass your objects from one process to another, and those process happen to live at different times and on different machines, then what you are looking at is more **messenging** than **serialization**.

There are efficient messenging libraries out there: Google's [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or Apache's [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) are good examples.

The key idea is to externalize the definition of the message to make it both platform (and compiler) agnostic, and then generate code bindings from that definition. Then from your code you'll create the message in-memory, serialize that message (xml/json/binary) and then on another platform deserialize the message into another in-memory representation.

If it feels like a supplementary step, well it is. On the other hand, it means that the message format is no longer tied to the inner implementation (layer of indirection...) and therefore you get the ability to change your inner implementation at will whilst still being able to read/write a message in various versions (for interactions with older deployed versions of the program for example).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to identify a type in a generic and portable way for serialization?

It is possible in a generic but non-portable way.

The string returned from `std::type_info::name()` is often a mangled type name that uniquely identifies a type. This name can be used to identify the type of serialized objects.

Name mangling differs from a compiler to a compiler, so a program compiled with another compiler may fail to read serialized objects.